# Sort NSArray with custom selector

Tags: nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I need to sort an NSArray of objects, but the sort has to be based on a calculation.

So, I think I must use a custom selector, where I do the math, and return the value do be sorted.

Goal: sort an NSArray based on the nr of days to a certain date. The startDate is in the Object, but I have to calculate the nr of days between the date of the object and another date.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Done:

```
NSArray *sorted = [[finalPTArray objectAtIndex:0] sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                        ^NSComparisonResult(PT *obj1, PT *obj2)
                        {
                            long nrOfDays_Obj1 = 0;

                            if (obj1.detail.legalDate)
                                nrOfDays_Obj1 = [RLCalendricalCalculations daysBetweenDate:[NSDate date] andDate:obj1.detail.legalDate];
                            else
                                nrOfDays_Obj1 = [RLCalendricalCalculations daysBetweenDate:[NSDate date] andDate:obj1.detail.requestDueDate];


                            long nrOfDays_Obj2 = 0;

                            if (obj2.detail.legalDate)
                                nrOfDays_Obj2 = [RLCalendricalCalculations daysBetweenDate:[NSDate date] andDate:obj2.detail.legalDate];
                            else
                                nrOfDays_Obj2 = [RLCalendricalCalculations daysBetweenDate:[NSDate date] andDate:obj2.detail.requestDueDate];


                            if (nrOfDays_Obj1 < nrOfDays_Obj2)
                                return NSOrderedAscending;
                            else if (nrOfDays_Obj1 > nrOfDays_Obj2)
                                return NSOrderedDescending;
                            else
                                return NSOrderedSame;
                        }];
```